# Background color hover

Tags: css, hover, background-color

How did they make the background color on hover look like that and not look like a box  on the "about" and "case study" areas? http://clorova.com/

Answer (score 0):

They used an image:

http://clorova.com/assets/img/general/hover.png

If you just inspect the page you will see the css:

```
.flare-hover:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    background-image: url(../img/general/hover.png);
    background-size: cover;
    top: -200px;
    left: -100px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.4);
    -o-transform: scale(0.4);
    transform: scale(0.4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They use image on ::before

```
  .flare-hover:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 450px;
        height: 450px;
        background-image: url(../img/general/hover.png);
        background-size: cover;
        top: -200px;
        left: -100px;
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.4);
        -o-transform: scale(0.4);
        transform: scale(0.4);
    }
```